# Converting values to dates in R

Tags: r, as.date

I have a very simple question

I have this value:

```
x <- 19630730
```

with class `numeric`. The `as.Date()` **does not give** me the expected result: `1963-07-30`

what is the potential remedy to convert `x` to a date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to character first

```
x <- 19630730
as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "1963-07-30"
```

If you use `lubridate::ymd` you don't need to convert to character.

```
lubridate::ymd(x)
```